# How to make function run once inside setInterval

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi friends i have a trouble while doing this ..

```
     getSocketPerSecond = function () {
            Interval_PerSecond = setInterval(function () {
              $.ajax({
                url: "/asset/ashx/GetSocket.ashx",
                type: "post",
                success: function (data) {
                switch (Status) {
                    case "opendoor":                        
                     openDoor();
                        break
                    case "closedoor":
                     closeDoor();
                        break                 
                }
            }, error: function () { }
        })
    }, 500)
}

function openDoor(){
console.log('Open Door');}

function closeDoor(){
console.log('Close Door');}
```

the console log coming this

```
ajax request // opendoor string
Open Door
ajax request
Open Door
ajax request
Open Door
ajax request // closedoor string
Close Door
ajax request
Close Door
ajax request
Close Door
```

i wish the console would be like this

```
 ajax request
Open Door
 ajax request
 ajax request
 ajax request
 ajax request
Close Door
 ajax request
 ajax request
 ajax request
 ajax request
```

i tried to make it but really no idea to do function run once since the ajax in repeat, so i need help .
thousand of thank .

Comment: You have to maintain request count in variable then use that count to check do you want to display in console or not

Comment: Where is the variable `Status` coming from?

Comment: the status is coming from server from GetSocket.ashx

Comment: Not in the current code it isn't. Should `Status` be read from `data` in some way?

Comment: @Yogesh what is that mean ?  but how is the `count` to count a frequent request. and the result comes out no idea is `OpenDoor` or `CloseDoor`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to keep track of the last status that has been handled so you can tell when it changes:

```
getSocketPerSecond = function () {
    var lastStatus;

    Interval_PerSecond = setInterval(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/asset/ashx/GetSocket.ashx",
            type: "post",
            success: function (data) {
                if (lastStatus === Status) {
                    return;
                }

                lastStatus = Status;

                switch (Status) {
                    case "opendoor":                        
                        openDoor();
                    break
                    case "closedoor":
                        closeDoor();
                    break                 
                }
            },
            error: function () { }
        })
    }, 500)
}

function openDoor() {
    console.log('Open Door');
}

function closeDoor() {
    console.log('Close Door');
}
```